# Windows 8 can not access the site of wamp from other computer on local network

Tags: windows, apache, wamp

I have installed

```
windows 8
Wamp server
```

here i have added my local site but as you know i am able to access

```
http://localhost/test
```

from the this computer where i have installed wamp the ip address is like=10.0.1.1
now from thei computer i can acess

```
http://10.0.1.1
```

but from other computer i can't access this 10.0.1.1 but it's connection is fine **i can ping it**

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause is you're being blocked by the firewall, make sure to add an exception to your firewall exception list to allow the connection.

Answer (score 1):

i solved the problem by disabling the firewall for port 80.

1. Go to Search on right side of windows.
2. search "firewall".
3. open the "firewall with advanced".
4. go to inbound rules.
5. click on "new rule".
6. select the "Port" option.
7. click "next"
8. select "TCP" option.
9. select "Specific local ports:".
10. type "80" in next text box
11. click next.
12. select the "Allow the connection".
13. click "next".
14. click "next".
15. give the name "Port 80 Allow Rule".
16. click "next".

**Note: this is not a secure way. delete this newly created rule when you complete your work.**